# Android: Have a non-intrusive activity transparent/unclickable activity running

Tags: android

Explaining this will be kind of a stretch but please bear with me. I've also put a visualization of what I want to do at the bottom of the post.

I have an app with 2 `Services` (A, C) and one `Activity` (B). The activity is absolutely needed to launch the second service because it creates a GUI that cannot be created from within the service itself as it needs an activity reference.

`Service A` is listening and once triggered, will launch `Activity B` which launches `Service C`.

Because I am currently out of ideas on how to let `Service A` communicate with `Service C` (C is already bound to B) I thought I would just launch the Activity every time `Service A` gets triggered and then hide the activity immediately.

Bad design aside this generally works but there is one major flaw: as I am constantly launching the activity (`launchMode="singleInstance"` so it doesn't stack up) it keeps appearing on screen preventing the user from interacting with their phone during that time. I do run `moveTaskToBack(true);` immediately to get that `Activity` to disappear as soon as possible but it's still visible for a few seconds.

Now I'd like to know how to

A) let `Service A` check whether `Activity B` and `Service C` are running (the user wouldn't mind the activity flashing up once per hour, I just don't want to bring it to front every 15 seconds)

or

B) Make `Activity B` "ontouchable" so the touches get passed through and the user doesn't notice it's on screen for a second (I've already made it transparent so the home screen is visible but it's still preventing the user from clicking anything on the homescreen)

[image]

Comment: I have thought about sending a broadcast, setting a `received` bool to false and if there is a reply from B and C, setting it to true. A second later it will check whether  `received` is true. This is pure nightmare code but for now that's the closest I got to getting this to work